# exception occurred in json parsing

Tags: json, windows-phone-8

I am trying to parse json. I am getting the following exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.Silverlight.DLL but was not handled in user code
```

my C# code is

```
private void imgloginbtn_Tap_1(object sender, 
                               System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e) {
  ///set flag in app.xaml for popup
  var obj = App.Current as App;
  obj.Popupflag = true;
  //WhatsupServices.WhatsUpServiceSoapClient ws = 
                    //new WhatsupServices.WhatsUpServiceSoapClient();
  WhatsupServices.WhatsUpServiceSoapClient ws = 
                  new WhatsupServices.WhatsUpServiceSoapClient();
  ws.ChangePasswrdJsonCompleted += ws_ChangePasswrdJsonCompleted;
  ws.ChangePasswrdJsonAsync("man", "man", "man");
}
void ws_ChangePasswrdJsonCompleted(object sender, 
                 WhatsupServices.ChangePasswrdJsonCompletedEventArgs e) {
  string s = e.Result;
  JObject obj = JObject.Parse(s);
  string ResultCode = (string) obj["ResultCode"];
  string ResponceMessage = (string) obj["ResponseMessage"];
}
```

Exception occurred when i am tring to get Resultcode

Help me how can i solve this problem?

Comment: What the string value of `e.Result`?

Comment: You could have an syntax error in your json. Please add it.

Comment: @AndreyShchekin:e.result={"ResultCode":0,"ResponseMessage":"Invalid password"}

Comment: @rekire:i am not geting your answer please elabrate it

Comment: You answered my question with the response to AndreyShchekin.

Comment: @renik:thanks renik it was syntax error. igot solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution of this exception.Actully my json return value in integer and i am doing type casting in string so it gives error.

my solution is:

```
string s = e.Result;
  JObject obj = JObject.Parse(s);
  int ResultCode = (int) obj["ResultCode"];
  string ResponceMessage = (string) obj["ResponseMessage"];
```